# How to add timer to change image for selected item in ListPicker

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

what would be the steps to add timer to change selected item's image in listpicker. Any suggestions? FYI, have never used ListPicker before. So i am finding it kind of hard to understand where to start and what to do.

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive about you want to achieve?  If you just got a list of images in the ListPicker.ItemSource, the only thing you have to do is make sure it is an ObservableCollection instead of a List and you can attach a DispatchTimer with some code to change the collection and it will update the ListPicker.

Comment: yes a list of images for itemsource but their appearances need to be controlled with a timer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need an ObservableCollection of your ImageSources and a DispatcherTimer to fire the events every TimeSpan of your choosing.

Here's some code to help you get started.  You can modify it to do exactly what you want.  It basically contains a ListPicker that has a collection of images as its ItemTemplate.  Every one second the DispatchTimer fires and switches the selectedItem's Image between the 2 default images that are created in about every single WP8.0 application.

Make it a habit to use ObervableCollection when you want to display something to the user instead of a List, it will make your WP8 development life a lot easier.

---

XAML

```XAML
    <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="my_listpicker" SelectionChanged="my_listpicker_SelectionChanged_1" Background="Black">
        <toolkit:ListPicker.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate/>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.HeaderTemplate>
        <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Background="Black">
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Height="200"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

---

C# Namespaces

```C#
using System.ComponentModel;                        // ObservableCollection
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;               // INotifyPropertyChanged
using System.Windows.Threading;                     // Dispatch Timer
```

---

C# Model of your Images (pretty basic, but pay attention to the INotifyPropertyChanged

```C#
public class MyBindingImage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyBindingImage() { }
    public MyBindingImage(string source)
    {
        this.ImageSource = source;

    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }


    string image_source;
    public String ImageSource {
        get { return image_source; }
        set
        {
            image_source = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImageSource");
        }
    }
}
```

---

C# (Create the Timer and ObservableCollection and Set the ItemSource)

```C#
DispatcherTimer timer;
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    // create our dispatch timer
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
    timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;

    InitializeComponent();

    // create our list picker elements
    ObservableCollection<MyBindingImage> my_image_list = new ObservableCollection<MyBindingImage>();
    my_image_list.Add(new MyBindingImage("Assets/ApplicationIcon.png"));
    my_image_list.Add(new MyBindingImage("Assets/AlignmentGrid.png"));            
    my_listpicker.ItemsSource = my_image_list;

}
```

---

C# Events (For the Timer & ListPicker SelectionChange)

```C#
// each time the selection has changd: stop the timer, then start it again
private void my_listpicker_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (timer != null)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
    }
}

// if the timer is on, cycle the images of the selected item
private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MyBindingImage item = (MyBindingImage) my_listpicker.SelectedItem;

        // cycle the selected image between to different images
        if (item.ImageSource == "Assets/AlignmentGrid.png")
        {
            item.ImageSource = "Assets/ApplicationIcon.png";
        }
        else
        {
            item.ImageSource = "Assets/AlignmentGrid.png";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error_message = ex.Message;
    }            
}
```

---

[APPLICATION SCREENSHOT]

[image]

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot. one thing i didn't understand that why have you put listpicket inside another listpicker?

Comment: My mistake.  Cutting and pasting code.  I will fix that. :D